# Excel Formula: Count Matches Where 2 IDs have a Common Tag

Tags: excel

I'm trying to figure out the most efficient way to do this in one cell's formula and would appreciate some assistance.

```
SHEET1
ID     TAG
123    Flowers
123    Sports
135    Sports
456    Flowers
456    Cars
123    Clouds
456    Sports

SHEET2
ID1    ID2   RESULT
123    456     2 [WANT TO CALCULATE THIS]
135    246     0 [WANT TO CALCULATE THIS]
```

The way the formula should work is look in SHEET1 where both ID1 and ID2 have a tag in common and count them.

Comment: Your expected output/logic makes no sense to me.  How are you arriving at these counts?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen sorry, if you look in Sheet 1, you will see 123 has 2 matches of common tags with 456 which are Flowers and Sports.  Does this help?

Comment: Check the formula solution I've posted and see if it helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach which should work for you.

Setup assumed:
Sheet1 data is in range `A1:B8`

Sheet2 data is in range `A1:B3`

Then formula that you should insert in `Sheet2!C2` shall be:

`=SUM((FREQUENCY(IFERROR(MATCH(IF(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$8=Sheet2!A2,Sheet1!$B$1:$B$8,"z"),IF(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$8=Sheet2!B2,Sheet1!$B$1:$B$8,"a"),0),"a"),IFERROR(MATCH(IF(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$8=Sheet2!A2,Sheet1!$B$1:$B$8,"z"),IF(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$8=Sheet2!B2,Sheet1!$B$1:$B$8,"a"),0),"b"))>0)+0)`

**NOTE:** This is an array formula and shall be inserted by committing CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER and not just ENTER. If entered correctly, Excel put {} braces around it.